# Prometheus alertmanager send mail only

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

i have prometheus alertmanager and simple rules

## prometheus.yml

- job_name: "Host_PRO"
  static_configs:

  - targets: ["192.168.0.17:9100"]
    labels:
    group: 'alert'
- job_name: "Host_PRE"
  static_configs:

  - targets: ["10.2.2.235:9100"]
    labels:
    group: 'noalert'
    name: 'PVE'

## alertmanager.yml

```
global:
  # The smarthost and SMTP sender used for mail notifications.
  smtp_smarthost: 'example:587'
  smtp_from: 'example'
  smtp_auth_username: 'example'
  smtp_auth_password: 'example'
  smtp_require_tls: true
route:
  group_by: ['alertname']
  group_wait: 10s
  group_interval: 10s
  repeat_interval: 24h
  routes:
    - match:
        group: alert 
      receiver: mail
receivers:
- name: 'mail'
  email_configs:
  - to: 'example@gmail.com'
```

## Example rules

```
- alert: NodeCPU_0_High
  expr: 100 - (avg by(instance, cpu) (irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle", cpu="0"}[1m])) * 100) > 80
  for: 2m
  labels:
    severity: critical
    app_type: linux
    category: cpu
  annotations:
    summary: "Node CPU_0 usage is HIGH"
    description: "CPU_0 load for instance {{ $labels.instance }} has reached {{ $value }}%"
```

How to send email only when host with group "alert" is to high ?

Comment: It's already configured this way, isn't it?

Comment: Unfortunately, my configuration does not work :(  Still gets emails from the noalert group

Comment: The only thing I came up with but works :)

[link](https://ibb.co/8BzHGxj)

Answer (score 0):

Set the following in alertmanager.yml file:

```
route:

  ...

  routes:
    - receiver: none
      matchers:
      - group != alert

    - receiver: mail
      matchers:
      - group = alert 

receivers:
  - name: none

  - name: 'mail'
    email_configs:
      - to: 'example@gmail.com'
```

Comment: @TMask have you tried this solution?